# Elasticsearch Query to Retrieve a Fixed Number of Documents from Each Index

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-query

I have an Elasticsearch setup with multiple indexes (let's say a, b, c, d, e, and f). My goal is to retrieve a total of 20 documents, with exactly 4 documents from each index. However, if any index has fewer than 4 documents, I want to fill in the remaining documents from other indexes.

For example:

```
a = 4
b = 4
c = 4
d = 4
e = 4
Total = 20
```

If any index has less than 4 documents:

```
a = 3
b = 4 or 5
c = 4 or 5
d = 4 or 5
e = 4 or 5
Total = 20
```

What should be the Elasticsearch query or payload to achieve this?

**Current approach**:

```
{
    "index": [
        "_all"
    ],
    "body": {
        "query": {
            "match_all": {}
        },
        "size": 20,
        "sort": {
            "created_at": "desc"
        }
    }
}
```

Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably use the [multi-search API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html) to do this and query each index separately, like this:

```
POST /_msearch
{"index": "a"}
{"size": 10, "sort": {"created_at": "desc"}, "query" : {"match_all" : {}}}
{"index": "b"}
{"size": 10, "sort": {"created_at": "desc"}, "query" : {"match_all" : {}}}
{"index": "c"}
{"size": 10, "sort": {"created_at": "desc"}, "query" : {"match_all" : {}}}
{"index": "d"}
{"size": 10, "sort": {"created_at": "desc"}, "query" : {"match_all" : {}}}
{"index": "e"}
{"size": 10, "sort": {"created_at": "desc"}, "query" : {"match_all" : {}}}
```

Also note that I'm retrieving more than 4 hits per index, for the case where an index would have less than 4 hits, you can pick another hit from another index.

Comment: In this kind of case, I need to pick hit from another index, is there any way to modify the query that we don't need to do it?

Comment: When retrieving the results, you can iterate over each response and pick the first 4 hits, if any index has less than 4 hits, you can decide to pick one more in the previous or next index.

Comment: Yes! I get that, but wanted a way to make elastic can do it.

Comment: All queries are independent from each other, so that's a little logic you should have in your code.

Comment: I want only 1 query to get the result, we can give the size 20, so even if I get documents only from index a and I can fill all 20.

Comment: Then you can use size 20 in the `_msearch` call and that will fulfill your requirement easily.

Comment: Can we do keyword search within msearch?

Comment: @AjayMakwana of course!